# Compile python source without constant folding optimization

Tags: python-2.7, bytecode, compiler-optimization, constant-expression, constantfolding

I have a python snippet as follows

```
5 + 6 * 8
```

Compiling this to AST gives:

```
>>> ast.dump(compile('5+6*8', '', 'eval', ast.PyCF_ONLY_AST))    
Expression(body=BinOp(left=Num(n=5), op=Add(), right=BinOp(left=Num(n=6), op=Mult(), right=Num(n=8))))
```

Note that in the generated AST `6 * 8` is **not** optimized into 48.

However, if I compile this generated AST and disassemble, `6 * 8` is replaced by `48`.

```
>>> astree = compile('5+6*8', '', 'eval', ast.PyCF_ONLY_AST)
>>> dis.disco(compile(astree, '', 'eval'))
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (5)
              3 LOAD_CONST               3 (48)
              6 BINARY_ADD          
              7 RETURN_VALUE
```

**My question**

How to compile the code to bytecode without the constant folding optimization? I need to do this for developing an obfuscator.

Comment: Maybe finding out why `5 + 48` wasn’t folded to `53` will guide to a solution. However, I don’t think that avoiding constant folding can be considered a strong obfuscation. Actually, it’s the opposite. The information that the constant `53` was derived from `5 + 6 * 8` (perhaps using named constants) in the source, is an information that is lost after folding and no decompiler can ever reconstitute…